# Drag & drop enabling in Kubuntu

Tags: 16.04, kubuntu, kde

How I can enable drag and drop? Like in ubuntu and other distros...
I only can add shortcuts to desktop with 'add to dekstop function'
when i drag it and drop it, it just appears in File Manager, but not desktop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. right click on Desktop, select **Configure Desktop**
2. in the Layout drop-down menu choose **Folder View**
3. accept changes

should enable the desktop, you are accustomed to!